# How Check ManyRelatedManager is None

Tags: python, django, database, orm, django-orm

-models.py

```
class Role:
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=100)

    comp = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="comp_roles")

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_roles',
                                    related_query_name='user_role',
                                    through='UserRole')

class UserRole(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

based on certain conditions I have two queries

-in api_views.py:

1-Role.objects.filter(comp_id=self.comp_id).prefetch_related('users')

2-Role.objects.filter(comp_id=self.comp_id)

-RoleSerializer.py

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_users(self, obj):

        #users: ManyRelatedManager = obj.users

        logger.info(f"this is obj.users: {obj.users}")
        logger.info(f"this is n obj.users: {obj.users == None}")

        # hit the db:
        # if not obj.users.all():
        # if obj.users.exists() == None:

        # no hit the db:
        # if obj.users.all() == None:
        # if obj.users == None:

        if obj.users.all() == None:
            logger.info(f"obj.users is None!")
            return None
        
        logger.info(f"obj.users is not None!")
        serializer = UserReadSerializer(obj.users.all(), many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Either **obj.users == None *log*** or **obj.users.all() == None *codition*** are always false!

My question is how can I find out obj.users or obj.users.all() (in RoleSerializer/get_users) is None?
so I can decide to return whether None or UserReadSerializer data.

Comment: `logger.info(f"this is obj.users: {obj.users.all()}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.users.all()` returns a queryset. so validating it against to None will not work. Instead you can use below line to get the count of entries and do your other operations on it.

```
obj.users.count()
```

if no users are present in the database for the model, it will return 0.

**Edit :** Saw one more answer posted for this question now.

```
obj.users.exists()
```

using exists is efficient than getting the count

**Edit:** Adding complete code .

**Views.py**

```
class RoleModelViewset(modelViewset):
    serializer_class = RoleSerializer
    queryset=Role.objects.filter(comp_id=self.comp_id).prefetch_related('users')
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_users(self, obj):
        if not obj.users.exists():
            logger.info(f"obj.users is None!")
            return None 
        logger.info(f"obj.users is not None!")
        serializer = UserReadSerializer(obj.users.all(), many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question,
I don't wanna check if there are obj.users.
In view (api view) layer I got to filter Role object, so based on some conditions I use prefetch to get the users (so users of role may or may not be contained in filtered qs).
now I wanna know, how can I find out whether obj (in RoleSerializer/get_users) contains users or not (which  might be sent from the view layer)

Comment: @SeyedMostafaSeyedAshoor added full answer.please check if it works for you

Comment: the above code you need to add in serializer get_users method. just replace if obj.users.all() == None: with the above if obj.users.exists(): . Also your two queries in views based on condition is not how you thought it would work. if you dont prefetch, it will query the db in your serializer (if you have any operation on the model) since you have users as a field in your Role model.

Comment: I've taught that your answer will hit the db more (with exists()), it turns out it does not!
so it's a complete answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there are entrys in a manyTomany field, you should use the exists method, this will return True or False.

```
if obj.users.exists():
    # do something
```